# Issue with GEKKO bspline for coolprop data in two-phase region

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to use coolprop inside my dynamic thermal simulation in gekko. I learned that rather than implementing coolprop calls directly bspline or cspline objects have to be used to allow gekko to find the derivatives. However, when attempting to do so in the two-phase region of the fluid, the bspline object does not lead to the correct results. Below is a minimal working example where I show the gekko results compared to a 2d spline from scipy. I am using a spline calculating the fluid´s temperature depending on the pressure and specific enthalpy.

```
import numpy as np
from CoolProp.CoolProp import PropsSI as PS
from gekko import GEKKO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import bisplrep, bisplev


def coolprop_bspline():
    # Gekko Setup
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    t_steps = 90
    m.time = np.linspace(0, 90, t_steps)

    # Initial values
    xi = 0.0
    p_i = 10e5
    tau_i = PS('T', 'Q', xi, 'P', p_i, 'R134a')
    h_i = PS('H', 'Q', xi, 'P', p_i, 'R134a')
    tau_low = tau_i - 30
    tau_high = tau_i + 30

    # Prepare spline data
    h_low = PS('H', 'T', tau_low, 'P', p_i, 'R134a')
    h_high = PS('H', 'T', tau_high, 'P', p_i, 'R134a')
    h_range = np.squeeze(np.linspace(h_low, h_high, 50))
    p_range = np.linspace(9.0e5, 11e5, 10)
    h_mesh, p_mesh = np.meshgrid(h_range, p_range, indexing='ij')
    tau_mesh = np.reshape(
        PS('T', 'H', np.reshape(h_mesh, (h_mesh.size,)), 'P', np.reshape(p_mesh, (p_mesh.size,)), 'R134a'),
        h_mesh.shape)

    # Variables
    h = m.Var(h_i)
    p = m.Var(p_i)
    tau = m.Var(tau_i)

    # Equations
    m.Equations(
        [
            h.dt() == 1000,
            p.dt() == 0,
        ]
    )
    m.bspline(h, p, tau, h_range, p_range, tau_mesh, data=True, kx=3, ky=3)

    # Execution
    m.options.IMODE = 4
    m.options.SOLVER = 3
    m.solve(disp=True)

    # Evaluate comparative spline from Scipy
    spl = bisplrep(h_mesh, p_mesh, tau_mesh, kx=3, ky=3)
    h_new = np.linspace(h_low, h_high, 200)
    p_new = np.linspace(9.0e5, 11e5, 200)
    h_new, p_new = np.meshgrid(h_new, p_new, indexing='ij')
    tau_interp = bisplev(h_new[:, 0], p_new[0, :], spl)

    # Plotting

    # Plot result from Gekko
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(h.value,tau.value)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('Enthalpy [J/kg]')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature [K]')
    plt.title('Gekko results with p = 1e6')

    # Plot comparative spline from scipy
    fig = plt.figure(2)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(h_new, p_new, tau_interp)
    ax.view_init(20, -100)
    plt.xlabel('Enthalpy [J/kg]')
    plt.ylabel('Pressure [Pa]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Temperature [K]')
    plt.title('Correct BSpline')

    # Plot original data from coolprop
    fig = plt.figure(3)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(h_mesh, p_mesh, tau_mesh)
    ax.view_init(20,-100)
    plt.xlabel('Enthalpy [J/kg]')
    plt.ylabel('Pressure [Pa]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Temperature [K]')
    plt.title('Raw coolprop data')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    coolprop_bspline()
```

Below are the resulting graphs. When comparing the Gekko result with the other two, it is obvious that the temperature should not suddenly increase to the maximum value covered by the splines at an enthalpy of around 335000 J/kg.

[image: Results from Gekko]

[image: Raw coolprop data]

[image: Correct spline from Scipy]

Does anyone have an idea of how to adjust the bspline object to correctly fit the data? So far I have already tried different polynomial degrees (kx, ky) as well as logarithmic inputs for pressure and enthalpy.

Answer (score 0):

Gekko can either generate a bspline from data or else use the knots and coefficients from another bspline generator. Here is an [example](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline) of using the knots and coefficients from another generator.

[image: bspline]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
#knots and coeffs
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
tx = [ -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
ty = [ -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
c = [1.0, 0.33333333, -0.33333333, -1.0, 0.33333333, 0.11111111, -0.11111111,
 -0.33333333, -0.33333333, -0.11111111, 0.11111111, 0.33333333, -1.0, -0.33333333,
 0.33333333, 1.0]
x = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
y = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
z = m.Var(2)
m.bspline(x,y,z,tx,ty,c,data=False)
m.Obj(z)
m.solve()
```

Gekko can also generate the bspline from data

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
#raw data
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
xgrid = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
ygrid = xgrid
z_data = x*y
x = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
y = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
z = m.Var(2)
m.bspline(x,y,z,xgrid,ygrid,z_data)
m.Obj(z)
m.solve()
```

but I'd recommend that you use the one that you generated if you already have something that you'd like to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the reply John. However I am not sure if it answers my question. I was aware of the two methods Gekko has to generate splines and I am fine with using the one from the data. It just seems that it is not working with my input. The input seems to be fine when I use the scipy spline though. Could you take a look at my example and see if I made a mistake in the implementation in gekko or elsewhere?